# Implementing themes in Silverlight 4 apps

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, themes

I have a 2 part question:

1. Is there anything more to implementing themes than simply placing a `<toolkit:BlahBlahBlahTheme>` tag around all your content?
2. What is the pattern for switching out themes at runtime?  Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes in Silverlight 4 are implemented implicitly by including the styles in your assets and adding them as resources in your app.xaml file.

The best way to see it in action is to grab an existing app with a theme and see how it's done. Better yet, there are now standard 2010 templates for some new themes, see them here on Tim Heuers blog

http://timheuer.com/blog/

As for loading them dynamically, yes you can
http://www.ganshani.com/2009/12/16/dynamic-theme-in-silverlight-3/

Comment: This question is about SL4 and although the first part of this answer is correct, the second part regarding dynamic switching is wrong as it refers to an SL3 solution based on ImplicitStyleManager that is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

use silverlight toolkit to change theme.

http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/05/31/dynamically-apply-and-change-theme-with-the-silverlight-toolkit.aspx